# How to stop blurry images on Raspberry Pi Robot car?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I’m making a robot car using a Raspberry Pi. I’ve attached a raspberry pi camera on top of the car; the images are clear when the car isn’t moving but when it is moving the images are blurry. Is anyone aware of any solutions (either hardware or software) to stop the blurry images when driving?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is that as the car is moving, the camera is vibrating. You need to stabilise the camera or make your car move slower.